# Twitter Boostrap 3 different sized Images not re-sizing correct and overlapping another column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying my first Responsive design and have implemented Twitter Boostrap 3. I have got a side where I want to show an article with images and information.

I have created a Panel and inside the Panel I have on the left side a Main Image and Thumbnails below it with a Mouse Over Effect to replace the Main Image and on the right side an information box. Below 768 the two boxes will move below each other. Images can be uploaded, which means they can have different sizes.

I want a fixed height for the Main Image Box (#main-image-container), otherwise I would have a constant jumping, when I use the Mouse Over effect. Of course I also want to keep the ratio of width to height. And the maximum width of the Main Image Box should be the max column width of the left columns and not overlap the Info Box on the right and the Thumbnail Box (#thumb-container) max-width should be the same as the #main-image-container.

It looks like that I have pretty much managed to get it working for <1200 and up around 530 on a landscape image. Above 1199, my picture width overlaps the Info Box and below the 530, the image width is not getting smaller anymore. I am trying to fix this now for a week, but can not find the solution. What do I do wrong here? I hope everybody understands my question and that my Sourcecode below helps.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">title</h3>
</div>

<div class="panel-body">

    <!-- Left Column of Advert -->
        <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 item_gallery" id="gallery">

            <div id="main-image-container" class="text-center">
                <div class="main-img-box">
                   <img src="/uploads/tmp/mainimage.jpg" class="img-responsive" id="main-img" width="400">
                </div>
            </div>
        <div id="thumb-container">
          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 thumb-img-box">
              <img src="/uploads/tmp/thumb/thumbimage1.jpg" class="thumbnails">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 thumb-img-box">
              <img src="/uploads/tmp/thumb/thumbimage2.jpg" class="thumbnails">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 thumb-img-box">
              <img src="/uploads/tmp/thumb/thumbimage3.jpg" class="thumbnails">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 thumb-img-box">
              <img src="/uploads/tmp/thumb/thumbimage4.jpg" class="thumbnails">
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Right Column -->

    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
           Here is a Bookmark Link
           <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading"><strong><span style="font-size:16px;&quot;">
                  Some Information
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li>lots of infos</li>
                        <li>more infos</li>
                    </ul>    
                </div>
           </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h4>Description</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 #main-image-container{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 90%;
    height: 452px;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    display: table;
}

.main-img-box{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: none;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 90%;
  height: 452px; 
}

// below is new
#main-img{
  max-height: 450px; 
}

#thumb-container{
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  display: table;
}

.thumb-img-box{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: none;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 1199px) {

  #main-image-container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 452px;
  }

  .main-img-box{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 452px; 
  }

  #main-img{
    max-height: 452px;
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  #thumb-container{
    height:100px;
  }

  .thumbnails { 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  }

  img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
   #main-image-container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 352px;
  }

  .main-img-box{
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 352px; 
  }

  #main-img{
    max-height: 352px;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  #thumb-container{
    max-height:100px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  img{
    width: 100%;
  }
```

Comment: can you share the entire html code? I ran it on my local web (using py predefined stylesheets and scripts) and it works fine

Comment: I don't think there is much more important code I could post. Have you tried it with images which are bigger than the actual column width? The solution below solved part of the problem, but the jumping on Mouse Over is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi in bootstrap you need to give display as inline-block then only images will be responsive.

```
    img
    {
        display:inline-block;
        width:100%;
    }
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks so much !! This solved the width and removed the overlapping of the right box as well as the problem with smaller resolutions. How easy that was. The only problem I now got left is that the height is still jumping on the Mouse Over effect, when I have different heights. Is there such an easy solution for that as well?

Comment: May be you have given different height ,or some padding/margin  on hover so just inspect code in browser and check these for hover it will solve your problem .

Comment: I have add a max-height and the jumping is gone (see above update), but I actually realised that even if the image gets now smaller on <768 the ratio is now wrong. Below 768 I jump from 2 columns (col-7 and col-5) to 1 column (col-xs-12), so the Image column and below that the details. The image gets now displayed with width 100% so of course on Portrait the ratio is now wrong. Boh is that confusing.

Comment: Can you please create  jsfiddle so that I can tell what is the exact solution?

Comment: so, I finally got jsfiddle to work, have never used it before. Here the link.  https://jsfiddle.net/Lukam/hx6zs7xd/12/ you can see when you change the size that the Ratio is not working on a vertical Image. The ratio is correct, when I remove the  max-width:220px; for @media (max-width: 767px) but then the the image overlapps again on a horizontal image, when I make the window smaller.